# Can I create an app that functions as a web app for Roku TV?

Tags: web-applications, roku, television, brightscript

I'm wondering if it's possible to create an app that functions as a web app on the Roku platform. Essentially, I want to build an application that users can access and interact with directly from their Roku TVs using a web-based interface.

Is this feasible, and if so, what tools or technologies should I consider using for this project? Any guidance or resources you can provide would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

My current app are basically an html with an application window.href.location pointing to the url of the developed app. But for Roku, I still have no idea how to do this

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately this is not possible on the Roku platform. They have no html/css/javascript or browser support of any kind.

The exception to this is the highest profile partners like YouTube or Disney. They have exclusive access to Roku's NDK (native development kit) which means they can write in C++ and can leverage browser-based tech. However, Roku rarely gives out NDK access, so essentially the answer is still "no" for everyone other than the top 5.